# Como desativar o botão de enviar até que o campo seja preenchido?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo que o botão fique desabilitado e seja habilitado somente quando o usuário digitar um número no campo de input, já tentei de várias formas usando JS, olhei vários fóruns, mas não tive sucesso ainda.

meu código HTML:

```
  <div class="box-cartao">
        <button type="submit" id="btnContinuar" onclick="continuar()">Continuar</button>
        <div class="login-box">
          <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <label for="input">
              Digite seu CPF
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

creio que para fazer isso que de modo dinâmico o ideal seria fazer o uso do JavaScript, recomendo esse post aqui do próprio Stack Overflow, que pode sanar sua dúvida com relação a isso (Está em Inglês): [Desabilitando botão de envio até que todas as lacunas estejam preenchidas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values)

Mas para bom começo de solução quanto a sua duvida o ideal seria fazer uso do `disabled`, ficando assim:

```html
  <div class="box-cartao">
        <button type="submit" id="btnContinuar" disabled>Continuar</button>
        <div class="login-box">
          <div class="user-box">
            <input type="text" id="input">
            <label for="input">
              Digite seu CPF
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: eu li esse post e tentei adaptar pro meu código, mas não funcionou :(